# Add xUnit test project to an existing Visual Web Developer 2010 express MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xunit.net, visual-web-developer-2010

Maybe it's very easy but I'm trying to add support for xUnit in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express. I followed this [tutorial](http://jayhollingum.blogspot.ca/2011/05/vwd-express-2010-unit-tests-with-xunit.html) on how to install everything but the main problem is that this tutorial only show how to add a test project to a **new project** and not to an existing one. When I do "Add New Project", there is not "xunit" or "test project" anywhere...

Anybody know how or can point me to a good tutorial?

Comment: May I advice to download Visual Studio 2012 Express? That has support for unit test out of the box and there is a good xUnit test runner that you can install.

Comment: @WouterdeKort Good idea. Not sure there are xUnit templates though (even if you install the xUnit.net runner VS extension)

Comment: @RubenBartelink yeah, that's true. I always use a regular class library and add xUnit trough NuGet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A standard Windows Library (.DLL) project will work fine and is the normal project type used for xUnit.net Tests - all the existing mechanism really added was the inclusion of some example tests to start you off.

This (not having templates) is the approach being taken with future xUnit versions. You'll find [some discussion of the reasoning behind this](http://xunit.codeplex.com/discussions/272171) on http://xunit.codeplex.com/discussions

Comment: So all the folders that are created are just examples and suggestion on how the test should be placed in the project? Anyway, I will create a new project on the side and check this out!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCôté Yes, they're just starters (albeit pretty good ones - obv Jim and Brad have great taste and not a little experience of these kinda things) - you won't find 2 people who have done serious test or TDD work for more than 6 months agreeing on any structure -  yes, even if they've read ttp://manning.com/osherove :P